# how to style mapbox polygon dots while editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-map-gl along with maplibre-gl

my style.json looks like so:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "localsource": {
      "type": "raster",
      "tiles": [
        "https://example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ],
      "tileSize": 256,
      "attribution": "© <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "locallayer",
      "source": "localsource",
      "type": "raster"
    }
  ]
}
```

The user is able to create and delete polygons which is fine,
however while painting the polygons the dots seem too small for mobile use.
I would like to increase their size while the polygon is being made

[image]

is there something I can add to the style.json to change their appearance?
I looked the whole day throughout the docs of mapgl but could not understand how to achieve that.
say for example increase the radius to 5 or 10 instead of 3 and maybe even change the color?